# Dynamic Bootstrap cards with content-wise width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ejs, bootstrap-cards

What is the way for creating bootstrap cards dynamically with the fixed height and width depending on the length of text. Now all the cards are aligned by columns, but I want a fixed margin between them.

```
<div class="row tree">
    <% for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) { %>
    <div class="col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <div class="card h-100 tree-obj">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= tree[i].name %></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Any updates? any help will be much appreciated.